# COM registration : handle ProgID for two versions of software

Tags: c++, com, registry

I am creating a new version of the software and there is a requirement that the new version(version 2) of software to run alongside with the previous software (version 1)

Currently, when version 1 of software uninstalls, it removes the ProgID in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ProgID, thus it impacts version 2 from running properly.

My questions:

1. Do I need to create new ProgID for version 2 ? There are numerous ProgID in the software.
2. Or should I use a version independent ProgID ? Does CLSIDFromProgID() function works with version independent ProgID ? MSDN does not seems to say it.
3. Or the code should not use CLSIDFromProgID() to get the CLSID ?

Please advice the proper way to handle ProgID for different version of software ?

Thank you

Comment: Boilerplate for a new ProgID is "Foo.Bar.2" so clients that want to take advantage of your new capabilities can find it.  Of course, "Foo.Bar" is only truly a version independent ProgID when you ensured that your new component doesn't break the version 1 clients.  That's work.